# Flutter secred storage

Tags: flutter, security, storage

what is difference between this two storage option?

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage

This two libraries based on the same or different implementation? If I have root on smartphone I can read data from application files saved using this storage? Which library is better/more safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is encrypted, second is not.

So first is more secured